# How to make the spacing between two widgets displayed in a 3 column grid equal in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code, which loops thrice to create three label widgets,

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

frm = tk.Frame(master=root, bg="yellow")
frm.columnconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2), weight=1)

for i in range(3):
    tk.Label(master=frm, text=i, bg="red", padx=40, pady=10).grid(row=0, column=i)

frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

gives the following output (as one would expect):

[image]

But, the following code, which only loops twice to create two label widgets,

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

frm = tk.Frame(master=root, bg="yellow")
frm.columnconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2), weight=1)

for i in range(2):
    tk.Label(master=frm, text=i, bg="red", padx=40, pady=10).grid(row=0, column=i)

frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Gives this output:

[image]

As you can see, the two widgets are not properly spaced out. I wanted to get this kind of output:

[image]

How do I achieve this? Why is the spacing uneven as in output #2?

Please keep in mind that I want to do this without creating any other label widgets as I am using a similar method to display search results in an application that I'm making using tkinter. I asked this question because I am facing the same issue in that application when I try to display only two search results or only one search result.

Thanks in advance for answering! And please bare with me as I'm only a beginner at tkinter.

PS: I know this deviates a bit from the question, but if you can point me to some sources/tutorials where I could better learn more about how tkinter works, please do!

Note: I'm using Python v3.8.5

Comment: tkdocs.com has a lot of valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the spacing uneven as in output #2?

The reason is because you are three columns a weight of 1 even though you're only using two columns.

If your goal is three equal sized columns, you should be using the `uniform` option. `weight` only applies to unused space, it in no way guarantees equal sized columns.

To get three equal sized columns, set `uniform` to the same value for all three columns. It doesn't matter what the value is, as long as it's the same for all columns.

```
frm.columnconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2), weight=1, uniform="equal")
```

This is the result:

[image: screenshot]