# How to make tkinter's `expand` give equal gaps between widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

If you `.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True)` 3 widgets, you get this:

[image: tkinter with unequal gaps]

[Image's source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64157406/5810023); same is true with `.grid(...)`.

Notice that there are 4 vertical gaps:  left, two in the middle, right.  However, the gaps on left and right are half of those in the middle.

My question is:  how to make `expand` work more evenly, so that all of the four vertical gaps are equal?

[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm) is `.pack`'s man page in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using `.grid()`.  You need to put those labels in column 1,3,5 and set `weight=1, uniform=1` on column 0,2,4,6 using `.columnconfigure()`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

frm = tk.Frame(master=root, bg="yellow")
# set weight=1 and uniform=1 on column 0,2,4,6
frm.columnconfigure(index=(0,2,4,6), weight=1, uniform=1)

# put labels in column 1, 3, 5
for i in range(1, 6, 2):
    tk.Label(master=frm, text=i, bg="red", padx=40, pady=10).grid(row=0, column=i)

frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]